# How can I check my svn connection?

Tags: svn, connection

How can I check my svn connection?

I just want to try to connect to server and check the status of my connection.. After that I will do something like check out and etc. well may be another way to get it?

Comment: Why do you need to check the connection? If you commit and it's not working the commit will fail...where is the problem?

Comment: @khmarbaise For example if the svn command is deep inside a complex bash script and you want to check all external connections before engaging.

Comment: That will not really help because if check before hand it could even fail at the real execution...so the script etc. should do correct error handling/checking...

Answer (score 17):

If you do not have any checked-out working copy, you can use

```
svn ls svn://server/repo
```

which lists contents of the repository if connection is successfull.

Other parameters like `--username ABC --password XYZ` and `--non-interactive` can be useful too if you are e.g. testing your credentials validity. Also, adding `--depth empty` should produce empty output if it succeeds (could be useful for scripting purposes).

Answer (score 10):

Simply issue `svn log` and see if it fails.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer OP asked what to do before check out...

Comment: None of these answers work.
The OP wants to *quickly* check connectivity for scripting purposes.
I want to *quickly* check to see if an svn connection will hang, without having to wait 60+ seconds for a connection to timeout.
'svn log' in particular takes forever, because it retrieves the log of the entire repository which can take minutes for a large repository.

Comment: Does not work from a client that has not checked out any files yet.

Answer (score -1):

Like Johannes already told you can use `svn log` to check the connection. If you want to see which settings apply to your current working copy use `svn info`.

Comment: Does not work from a client that has not checked out any files yet.

Answer (score -2):

Just call http get on any SVN url like:

```
https://username:password@server/repo
```