# How to quickly check svn repository connectivity for scripting purposes

Tags: svn

My build script hangs for 60+ seconds if svn repository is in a bad state or network connectivity is compromised in some way.

I want to quickly check to see if an svn command will hang, without having to wait 60+ seconds for a connection to timeout.

A simple 'ping' of the server is not sufficient.  Server may be reachable but repository may be responding slowly for some reason.

'svn log' in particular takes forever, because it retrieves the log of the entire repository which can take minutes for a large repository.

None of the answers here work:
[How can I check my svn connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809173/how-can-i-check-my-svn-connection)

Comment: What does "bad state" and "network connectivity" actually mean? Have you considered resolving those issues first?

Comment: When team members are VPN'd to svn server on the other side of the planet, the tcp connection is flaky and the svn compilation script often hangs.